# Using MTOM with StreamingAttachment - failing on jetty start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jetty, mtom

please advise!

Defined on server side:

/////////////////
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true)
@MTOM(threshold=10000000 )
/////////////////

Everything compiles with no errors.

When jetty is started, below error is shown:

2012-05-16 04:31:48.403::INFO:  jetty-6.1.4
SEVERE : May 16, 2012 4:31:49 AM: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Annotation @com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.Str
mingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, dir=, memoryThreshold=1048576) is not recognizable, atleast one constructor of class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.StreamingAtta
mentFeature should be marked with @FeatureConstructor (com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener::contextInitialized)
         javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Annotation @com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, dir=, memoryThreshold=1048576) is not cognizable, atleast one constructor of class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.StreamingAttachmentFeature should be marked with @FeatureConstructor

Comment: that version of jetty is ancient, try using something more recent like 7.6.3.v20120416 for servlet 2.5 support or 8.1.4.v20120416 for servlet 3.0 support.

Comment: not that jetty really has any skin in the game on this issue, so don't update expecting that will fix it...figured it was probably worth mentioning that as well :)